# Python - Problems to install pywinauto module

Tags: python, pip, pywinauto

I've this modules:

```
import time
import os
import argparse
from pywinauto.application import Application
```

I'm not able to using pip because I've a lot of restrictions in my proxy and I can't install pip. When I use pip it gives me the following error:

I try to unzip the pywinauto module zip and extract them into the folder where I've setup.py and run in command line : `python setup.py install`

```
 Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )',))': /simple/pywinauto/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )',))': /simple/pywinauto/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )',))': /simple/pywinauto/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )',))': /simple/pywinauto/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )',))': /simple/pywinauto/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywinauto (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywinauto
```

However when run mu script I'm getting this:

```
File "C:\PROD\Open.py", line 4, in <module>
  from pywinauto.application import Application

builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywinauto'
```

How can I download this module in order to run my Python script?

Thanks

Comment: Try to install setuptools. Which Python version do you use?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov thanks! I'm using Python 3.6.4

Comment: See the installation instructions at https://pywinauto.github.io/